# Laravel Backpack not reflecting changes made to JS file on page refresh

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-backpack

Code based changes made to the javascript file that I am calling in setupCreateOperation() is not reflecting the changes made on page refresh.

```
    protected function setupCreateOperation(){
       Widget::add()->type('script')->content(asset('asset/user.js'));
       CRUD::setCreateView('users/create');
    }
```

[image]

**Attempted Solution**

*To add "versioning" to the JS file*

```
Widget::add()->type('script')->src(asset('asset/user.js?v=' . time()));
```

However this results in the javascript file no longer being called and with there also being no errors when inspecting the browser.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel backpack already handles the "versioning" of the js files as can be seen by the random characters added after user.js.

[image]

The changes were not reflected because the browser was still referring to the cached js file. Need to do hard refresh of browser rather than regular refresh

[image]